# Proof $X\backslash\bigcap \limits_{i\in\Lambda} A_i = \bigcup\limits_{i\in\Lambda} (X\backslash A_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a universe. Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in\Lambda}$ be a family of sets in $X$, where $\Lambda$ is a set of index.

I want to prove:

$$X\backslash\bigcap \limits_{i\in\Lambda} A_i = \bigcup\limits_{i\in\Lambda} (X\backslash A_i)$$

---

How do I prove this? It looks like a generalised de-morgans laws, but I don't understand how I can work with these without operators in and out of the iterated intersection/unions.

---

Comment: There are without a doubt other duplicates, some might be more helpful. But this one was the first on the list. Feel free to use the search function in order to find other versions of this question if the suggested one is not sufficient to answer your question; or edit your question to include more details as to what the answers are missing, and what you've got stuck with.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Mine appears to be the top one, thanks for that lovely